# KWin answer to Compiz Put and Grid?

Tags: compiz, shortcut-keys, kde

I have just recently switched from Ubuntu to Kubuntu. UI-wise I prefer KDE over Unity, I do however miss some of the Compiz plugins (especially the keyboard shortcuts). KWin seems to allow enormous amounts of keyboard shortcuts, but so far I haven't been able to find the correct ones. What I specifically miss is the Put/Grid plugins in Compiz that allowed placing and resizing of windows using different key combos plus the keypad. The closest I have come in KWin is the "Pack Window" and "Pack Grow Window" key shortcuts that behave roughly like the Put/Grig plugins except it lacks the finegrained control.

So in short:
Is there any way to get KWin key shortcuts to give the same finegrained control over size and placing of windows as Compiz Put/Grid (which had one place for each keypad key plus different sizes)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kwin in KDE does support this in Kubuntu 11.10
you can bind the shortcut under General shortcuts -> Kwin
Look for quick tile
I found that the numpad did not work in my setup for some so I used <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>/<kbd>W</kbd>/<kbd>E</kbd>/<kbd>A</kbd>/<kbd>S</kbd>/<kbd>D</kbd>/<kbd>Z</kbd>/<kbd>X</kbd>/<kbd>C</kbd> for my grid

I pasted a Kwinlayout .kksrc file that you can import:

> [kwin][Global Shortcuts] Activate Window Demanding
>   Attention=Ctrl+Alt+A Block Global Shortcuts=none Cube=Ctrl+F11
>   Cylinder=none Enable/Disable Tiling=Alt+Shift+F11 Expose=Ctrl+F9
>   ExposeAll=Ctrl+F10 ExposeClass=Ctrl+F7 FlipSwitchAll=none
>   FlipSwitchCurrent=none Kill Window=Ctrl+Alt+Esc Mouse
>   Emulation=Alt+F12 Move Window Down=Meta+Shift+J Move Window
>   Left=Meta+Shift+H Move Window Right=Meta+Shift+L Move Window
>   Up=Meta+Shift+K MoveMouseToCenter=Meta+F6 MoveMouseToFocus=Meta+F5
>   MoveZoomDown=Meta+Down MoveZoomLeft=Meta+Left MoveZoomRight=Meta+Right
>   MoveZoomUp=Meta+Up Next Layout=Meta+PgDown Previous Layout=Meta+PgUp
>   Remove Window From Group=none Setup Window Shortcut=none Show
>   Desktop=none ShowDesktopGrid=Ctrl+F8 Sphere=none Suspend
>   Compositing=Alt+Shift+F12 Switch Focus Down=Meta+J Switch Focus
>   Left=Meta+H Switch Focus Right=Meta+L Switch Focus Up=Meta+K Switch
>   One Desktop Down=Ctrl+Alt+Down Switch One Desktop Up=Ctrl+Alt+Up
>   Switch One Desktop to the Left=Ctrl+Alt+Left Switch One Desktop to the
>   Right=Ctrl+Alt+Right Switch Window Down=Meta+Alt+Down Switch Window
>   Left=Meta+Alt+Left Switch Window Right=Meta+Alt+Right Switch Window
>   Up=Meta+Alt+Up Switch to Desktop 1=Ctrl+F1 Switch to Desktop 10=none
>   Switch to Desktop 11=none Switch to Desktop 12=none Switch to Desktop
>   13=none Switch to Desktop 14=none Switch to Desktop 15=none Switch to
>   Desktop 16=none Switch to Desktop 17=none Switch to Desktop 18=none
>   Switch to Desktop 19=none Switch to Desktop 2=Ctrl+F2 Switch to
>   Desktop 20=none Switch to Desktop 3=Ctrl+F3 Switch to Desktop
>   4=Ctrl+F4 Switch to Desktop 5=none Switch to Desktop 6=none Switch to
>   Desktop 7=none Switch to Desktop 8=none Switch to Desktop 9=none
>   Switch to Next Desktop=none Switch to Next Screen=none Switch to
>   Previous Desktop=none Switch to Screen 0=none Switch to Screen 1=none
>   Switch to Screen 2=none Switch to Screen 3=none Switch to Screen
>   4=none Switch to Screen 5=none Switch to Screen 6=none Switch to
>   Screen 7=none Toggle Floating=Meta+F Toggle Window Raise/Lower=none
>   Walk Through Desktop List=none Walk Through Desktop List
>   (Reverse)=none Walk Through Desktops=none Walk Through Desktops
>   (Reverse)=none Walk Through Window Tabs=none Walk Through Window Tabs
>   (Reverse)=none Walk Through Windows=Alt+Tab Walk Through Windows
>   (Reverse)=Alt+Shift+Backtab Walk Through Windows Alternative=none Walk
>   Through Windows Alternative (Reverse)=none Window Above Other
>   Windows=none Window Below Other Windows=none Window Close=Alt+F4
>   Window Fullscreen=none Window Grow Horizontal=none Window Grow
>   Vertical=none Window Lower=none Window Maximize=Alt+Shift+S Window
>   Maximize Horizontal=none Window Maximize Vertical=none Window
>   Minimize=none Window Move=none Window No Border=none Window On All
>   Desktops=none Window One Desktop Down=none Window One Desktop Up=none
>   Window One Desktop to the Left=none Window One Desktop to the
>   Right=none Window Operations Menu=Alt+F3 Window Pack Down=none Window
>   Pack Left=none Window Pack Right=none Window Pack Up=none Window Quick
>   Tile Bottom Left=Alt+Shift+Z Window Quick Tile Bottom
>   Right=Alt+Shift+C Window Quick Tile Left=Alt+Shift+A Window Quick Tile
>   Right=Alt+Shift+D Window Quick Tile Top Left=Alt+Shift+Q Window Quick
>   Tile Top Right=Alt+Shift+E Window Raise=none Window Resize=none Window
>   Shade=none Window Shrink Horizontal=none Window Shrink Vertical=none
>   Window to Desktop 1=none Window to Desktop 10=none Window to Desktop
>   11=none Window to Desktop 12=none Window to Desktop 13=none Window to
>   Desktop 14=none Window to Desktop 15=none Window to Desktop 16=none
>   Window to Desktop 17=none Window to Desktop 18=none Window to Desktop
>   19=none Window to Desktop 2=none Window to Desktop 20=none Window to
>   Desktop 3=none Window to Desktop 4=none Window to Desktop 5=none
>   Window to Desktop 6=none Window to Desktop 7=none Window to Desktop
>   8=none Window to Desktop 9=none Window to Next Desktop=none Window to
>   Next Screen=Meta+4 Window to Previous Desktop=none Window to Screen
>   0=none Window to Screen 1=none Window to Screen 2=none Window to
>   Screen 3=none Window to Screen 4=none Window to Screen 5=none Window
>   to Screen 6=none Window to Screen 7=none view_actual_size=Meta+0
>   view_zoom_in=Meta+= view_zoom_out=Meta+-

Comment: Couldn't something similar be done with compiz?